# raspberry python prints empty b ' ' from a serial port

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors, uart, rs485

I want to connect a pressure sensor that use a RS485 communication to raspberry pi,
when I connected it to RS485 to UART converter to the raspberry
but when I ran the code the output is b'' with no numbers from the sensor
can anybody know how I can read from the sensor ?
'KITA' is the sensor I use.

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', 9600, timeout=0.1)'
ser.write(b'$PF,200\r\n')
ser.write(b'$PO,20\r\n')
x = ser.read()
print (x)
```

Comment: What driver(s) did you install for this **/dev/serial0** device node?  How exactly are you connecting this  converter to your RPi?  How have you verified that this connection is functional?  Or are you testing with multiple unknowns at once?

Comment: did you test this device with any other program? Did you try to `sleep()` before `read()` - so device and raspberry will have time to send/receive data?

Comment: I installed PYSERIAL, and I connecting the converter to the GPIO 14 and 15 (TXD AND RXD), I verified it via terminal and I can tell that the TXD,RXD LED was blinking every time I ran the code .
no I do not tested with any thing ales.

Comment: Does the RS-485 adapter require a half-duplex control line (e.g. RTS), or is it automatic?  Your read timeout is somewhat short for a rather slow baudrate.  For a WAG try the opposite, and use a blocking read, i.e. wait forever until something is received.